# How to use an angular function in my case?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have to hide some button in an html page and for this I wanted to use a line that is located in another html file of mine, the `ng-if="category.layers_count > 0"`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAPEu.png)

[image]

But when I tried to put it in my other file, it doesn't work and I don't know why.
This is how I tried to do it.

```
{% verbatim %}
<div ng-repeat="category in categories"</div>
{% endverbatim %}
<div  ng-if="category.layers_count > 0">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">

        <a target="_self" href="{% url "search" %}?limit=100&offset=0&category__identifier__in=biota">
            <div class="category" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto"
                title="{% trans "Flora and/or fauna in natural environment. Examples: wildlife, vegetation, biological sciences, ecology, wilderness, sealife, wetlands, habitat." %}">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf fa-3x"></i>
                <h4>{% trans "Biota" %}</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have the category object in your controller? also, you need to add " to your html properties, you're just stringing together non existing variables and strings

Comment: <div ng-repeat="category in categories"</div> check  this line you are not closing your div,